# How change format of timestamp after get from data base in php?

Tags: javascript, php, date, timestamp

I have this php:

```
<?php

    require "transferDao/daoTransferHistorial.php";

    require "bdconnection.php";


        class daoHistorial{


                public function sqlSelect(){

                        $aObjects=array();


                        $dbconn = new DBconnection();
                        $db = $dbconn->bdConnection();
                        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT t2.tar_id, t3.usu_nombre, t3.usu_apellido, t1.tar_nombre, t2.rea_porcentaje, t2.hrs_tarea, t2.tar_fechtermino, t1.tar_fechregist 
                                              FROM act_tarea t1
                                              inner join act_registtarea t2     
                                              on t1.tar_id = t2.tar_id
                                              inner join act_regisdiario t4
                                              on t2.rdi_id = t4.rdi_id
                                              inner join act_usuario t3
                                              on t3.usu_id = t4.usu_id");
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

                        foreach ($result as $row) {
                                $aTransfer = new daoTransferHistorial();
                                $aTransfer->setTareaId($row['tar_id']);
                                $aTransfer->setUsu_nombre($row['usu_nombre']);
                                $aTransfer->setUsu_apellido($row['usu_apellido']);
                                $aTransfer->setTar_nombre($row['tar_nombre']);
                                $aTransfer->setPorcentaje($row['rea_porcentaje']);
                                $aTransfer->setHrs_tarea($row['hrs_tarea']);

                                $aTransfer->setFecha_termino($row['tar_fechtermino']);
                                $aTransfer->setFech_registro($row['tar_fechregist']);
                                $aTransfer->setState(1);

                                $aObjects[]=$aTransfer;
                        }
                        return $aObjects;
                }   
        }
    ?>
```

here I get the date :

> $aTransfer->setFecha_termino($row['tar_fechtermino']);

in js I have this td:

```
 '<td class="text-center">'+value.fecha_termino+'</td>'+
```

and print the date of this way :

> 2015-06-07 00:00:00

and I need this format :

> 07-06-2015 00:00:00

where and how fix this? sorry my english.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$row['tar_fechtermino']= date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($row['tar_fechtermino']));
```

before

```
$aTransfer->setFecha_termino($row['tar_fechtermino']);
```

Comment: hi I have this problem now :  with message 'strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function

Comment: You probably need to put the timezone in a configuration line in your php.ini
for example - date.timezone = America/New_York
Or you can try to define it on your PHP script
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-06-07 00:00:00');
echo $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code :

```
$date="2015-06-07 01:50:40";
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

It will give following output :

> 07-06-2015 01:50:40

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do that on Client-side, here's the way:

```
var date = new Date("2015-06-07 00:00:00");
var formatedDate = ('00' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ('00' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + date.getUTCFullYear() + ' ' + ('00' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
```

Or a much simpler way using [Datejs](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs):

```
var date = new Date("https://github.com/datejs/Datejs").toString("dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

But if you can do that in Server-side it's much simpler:

```
$date = new DateTime("2015-06-07 00:00:00");
$formatedDate = $date->format("d-m-Y H:i:s")
```